# Python function to find similarity between differently formatted strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting, substring

I have 2 excel files with names of items. I want to compare the items but the only remotely similar column is the name column which too has different formatting of the names like

**KIDS-Piano** as *kids piano*

**Butter Gel 100mg** as *Butter-Gel-100MG*

I know it can't be 100% accurate so I would instead ask the human operating the code to make the final verification but how do I show the closest matching names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of doing this is writing a regular expression.

But the vanilla code below might do the trick as well:

```
column_a = ["KIDS-Piano", "Butter Gel 100mg"]
column_b = ["kids piano", "Butter-Gel-100MG"]

new_column_a = []
for i in column_a:
    # convert strings into lowercase
    a = i.lower()
    # replace dashes with spaces
    a = a.replace('-', ' ')
    new_column_a.append(a)

# do the same for column b
new_column_b = []
for i in column_b:
    # convert strings into lowercase
    a = i.lower()
    # replace dashes with spaces
    a = a.replace('-', ' ')
    new_column_b.append(a)

as_not_found_in_b = []
for i in new_column_a:
    if i not in new_column_b:
        as_not_found_in_b.append(i)

bs_not_found_in_a = []
for i in new_column_b:
    if i not in new_column_a:
        bs_not_found_in_a.append(i)

# find the problematic ones and manually fix them
print(as_not_found_in_b)
print(bs_not_found_in_a)
```

Comment: thanks @Gnoliz I did something similar to this but as you said, I took the words using RE by `re.findall(r"[\w]+", lst.lower())`